# javascript - closing a while loop after array.lenght = x

Tags: javascript, while-loop, prompt

given an array of 5 numbers i give to the user with an alert,
i want to ask 5 times a number to the user.
after i want to tell him how many numbers he remembered

My problem is that after that another prompt pops up and the game continues.
i want that after this working loop of 5 prompt, I don't get anymore prompt.

(without using BREAK)

i simplified the code, i had conditions console log and alerts here and there. i have problems with the LOGIC right now... can anyone help? thanks!!

```js
var numberList = [5, 6, 56, 76, 11];
//this variable was made before with 5 random numbers between 1 and 100
alert('Remember: ' + numberList);

var try;
var arrayRemembered = [];
var arrayRightTries = [];
var arrayTotalTries = [];

while (arrayTotalTries.length < 5) {
  var try = parseInt(prompt('digit a number between 1 and 100'));

  if (numberList.includes(try)) {
    arrayRightTries.push(try);
    arrayTotalTries.push(try);
  } else {
    arrayTotalTries.push(try);
  }
}

console.log('The numbers you remember: ' + arrayRightTries);
console.log('The numbers you had to remember: ' + numberList );
```

Comment: I mean, I could just "win" your game by "remembering" one number five times...

Comment: `try` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript. Don't use it for variable names.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes i know i am learning javascript this is just an exercise

Comment: @ThomasSablik thak you i didnt know that,  actually that is not the problem because i translated my code in english so the "original" code had "tentativo" instead of try, but i will remember that

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `try` is a reserved keyword. If you just rename it, it should work:

```js
var numberList = [5, 6, 56, 76, 11];
//this variable was made before with 5 random numbers between 1 and 100

alert('Remember: ' + numberList);

var tries;

var arrayRemembered = [];

var arrayRightTries = [];

var arrayTotalTries = [];

while (arrayTotalTries.length < 5) {

var tries = parseInt(prompt('digit a number between 1 and 100'));


if (numberList.includes(tries)) {
  arrayRightTries.push(tries);
  arrayTotalTries.push(tries);

   
} else {
    
  arrayTotalTries.push(tries);
   
}
}

console.log('The numbers you rememeber: ' + arrayRightTries);

console.log('The numbers you had to remember: ' + numberList );
```

**Edit:** This is unrelated to the question, but I'd suggest using a `Set` for storing remembered numbers so that you cannot win the game by just remembering one number.

Comment: Thank you lacrit.
To tell you the truth my problem was that all that code was in a setInterval function.
After i was certain that the code i posted was good  i went to study setInteval tried using clearInteval ( no luck ) but i resolved my problem using setTimeout instead .
Thank you ppl